# How do I put a button to the left of the button in the bottom right of my ktinker program?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-layout, tkinter-button

I'm trying to write a program with ktinker with buttons in the top/bottom left and the top/bottom right. The issue is, I cannot put any buttons next to pre-existing buttons, only next to them, how would I do this?

```
#Welcome text and version number
Label(root, text="Wecome to %s" % banicVer).place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

#Confirm button
#Button(root,text="Confirm\nand Save", command=root.destroy,).pack(side=BOTTOM,anchor=SE)
Button(root,text="Confirm\nand Save", command=root.destroy,).pack(side=BOTTOM,anchor=SE)


#Revert
#Button(root,text="Reset\nBootscreen", command=root.destroy,).pack(side=LEFT,anchor=SE)
Button(root,text="Reset\nBootscreen", command=root.destroy,).pack(side=BOTTOM,anchor=SE)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is easier to put the buttons in a frame and then put the frame at the bottom right.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I'm new to tkinter so didn't know how to use frames but this seems to be the best solution

Comment: it looks like you have missed part of the code : the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example